# Precision Trouble with go-fish

Tags: esoteric-languages

I'm challenging myself to solve as many Project Euler problems as I can in ><> (https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish). For problem 20, factorial digit sum, I have this code:

```
>::?\~|     ;oan/? -\
\ -1/*l1\/a,:0)?\+l1/
    ^? -/\-}:%a:<
```

Where the number to use starts on the stack. It works perfectly for an input of 10, however, when I put in 100 on the online ><> interpreter (https://fishlanguage.com/playground) the factorial digits lose accuracy after about 14 digits, presumably because the interpreter doesn't support arbitrary precision. I got the go-fish interpreter to try and combat this, but now it's giving -1045, even using the -m command. I assume this is an overflow error, is there a way to fix this? Or will I have to get the fish.py interpreter?